# Playing flash from a certain frame

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2

So I'm creating a movie clip using flash... Is there any way to start playing the movie from a certain frame (lets say frame 550) which I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
So I don't have to watch the entire movie to test it?

gotoAndPlay(550) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you make sure to call the gotoAndPlay(550) inside the movie clip/using the instance name

Answer (score 0):

gotoAndPlay(550) should work, are you sure you have content on that frame for the movie to land at?

You can also use labels where you give a frame a label in the properties panel and then you can use: gotoAndPlay("labelName").

If you are using it on a button you can do:

```
on (release) {
  gotoAndPlay(550);
}
```

Check this out for more info: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=181948

Comment: It doesn't work =\ I only want to skip right to the section that I'm making to see how it turns out...

Comment: You need to put the actionscript on the keyframe you want to use if you only want to go without actions. I've got an example for you that I'm uploading.

Comment: Hmm It seems it'll not work, since there are some scripts in between and they're interfering with the gotoAndPlay().. oh well.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.multiupload.com/K3G0UQSDQ8

It is usually a good idea to put all scripts on it's own layer to make it easy to separate them. You really should be using AS3 as that is much easier to control.